# Calculating a percentage with mouse position considering half-circle

Tags: javascript, raphael, graphael, justgage

I just tried to code some tricks on justGage (using Raphael JS code) to calculate percentages but I'm stuck on mathematical formula :( .

Here's the point : 
I have a div with 400px width that welcomes a svg justGage.
I would like to make it filling following mouse clicking. For example, clicking on bottom right of the half-circle will fill it as if it was 100% filled. Clicking on bottom left, fill it at 0%.
The issue is that I try to catch mouse position and use it to refresh the Gage, but working only on X axis is not following circle shape.

Here's my basic calculation :

```
    var parentOffset = $(this).offset(); 
    var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    g1.refresh(Math.round((relX)/4));
```

And the whole code test [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAB3k/).

Does anyone know a formula to really follow the circle shape ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a *strip* which the clicks happen, you cannot rely on the x-coordinate in order to decide the precentage. The best option I could think of was using trigonometry to calculate the angle between the click and the center of the circle, before fitting it to your range 0-100 by this equation (`(angel/Math.PI)*100`).

Below is a code snipplet that worked out for me.

```
$(function(){
    $("#g1 path").click(function(e){
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var height = parent.height();
        var width = parent.width();
        var center = {'x': width/2, 'y':(height-60)};
        var angle = Math.atan2(-(e.pageY - center['y']), center['x'] - e.pageX);
        g1.refresh(Math.round((angle/Math.PI)*100));  
    });
})
```

Comment: ok i did some other tests inside a page and it seems conflicting when there are other divs over. So I modified the script to make it always calculating pageY and X inside the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

here is a draft about the calculation:
[image: draft]

Comment: I measured angles in degrees.